# Will a reference to the Application context leak my retained fragment?

Tags: java, c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin

I have a fragment that does some background http calls and because I don't want the process to be interrupted by configuration changes the fragment is declared as retainedInstance.
Because the service needs to read tokens from the app's keystore, it needs a reference to a context. So, in the OnAttach method I grab a reference to the application context from the hosting activity:

```
public override void OnAttach(Android.App.Activity activity)
{
    base.OnAttach(activity);
    appContext = activity.ApplicationContext;
}
```

I can't reset this reference in OnDestroyView, because the fragment might still need it.

Will this reference to the Application context leak my fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because your `Application` is not pointing to the fragment; the fragment points to the `Application`.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure if there still existed a circular reference where the Application somehow points to the activity and the activity points to the fragment, but thanks for the confirmation, Mark!

Comment: @JannieT: `Application` does not hold onto activities and the like, unless you do that yourself in a subclass (which would then be a memory leak, unless managed carefully).

Comment: Can I assume that I should always try to use applicationContext when working with retainedFragments? Example, in the onCreate() method of the fragment I call  val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activityContext). If I rotate the device that would leak the activity hosting the fragment. Am I correct?

Comment: @feresr: In the specific case of `SharedPreferences`, they are process-level singletons in their own right, and so the framework is already taking steps to avoid memory leaks. However, in general, a retained fragment should ensure that its fields either are not tied to any `Context`, are tied to the `Application`, or are going to get updated after a configuration change (e.g., widgets getting recreated in `onCreateView()`).